# Checking if image has incorrect file extension

Tags: python, image, validation, file-type

If I have a random assortment of jpg, png, and tif images, and I cannot assume that the filename extension is accurate, what's the best way in Python to check that each image is really the extension type it says?

Comment: This is a very broad question. You'd have to read the header of each file and match it up with a file format. However there's probably a python library that could do it for you.

Comment: Are you assuming the files are all images of the specified formats and just unsure of the extensions matching the format, or do you also need to consider the case where the files aren't in one of the specified formats?

Comment: @CraigMeier In reality it'd be possible to get a none-of-the-above, but I'd be happy if I could at least validate those three.

Comment: @Loocid are there any python image or other libraries that facilitate this type of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `imghdr` module will guess image types based on the first several bytes of the file. It won't guarantee that the file is a valid image of the detected format, but nothing short of fully decoding the image will give you that.